# jython LookupError or ImportError

Tags: python, jython

Installed Jython 2.7.1, but looks like I cannot import some modules. I got following errors:

```
import json
File "json/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
File "/home/ec2-user/temp/jython271/Lib/json/decoder.py", line 24, in <module>
File "/home/ec2-user/temp/jython271/Lib/json/decoder.py", line 18, in _floatconstants
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding 'hex'

import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
File "httplib.py", line 72, in <module>
File "/home/ec2-user/temp/jython271/Lib/socket.py", line 3, in <module>
from _socket import (
File "_socket.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named encodings
```

Any ideas? I have python2.7 on linux, if I include python2.7 lib in the CLASSPATH, it seems can resolve first error, and can not get away from the second.

Comment: How did you install Jython 2.7.1? What's your operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is twofold:

1. You need to install Python 2.7 - it has a number of the code modules (like encodings) that you are trying to import.
2. You need to set the JYTHONPATH environment variable to the location of your Python 2.7 modules (usually /usr/lib/python2.7) - that is how Jython knows where to look to find modules.

Once you do those two things, an import of encodings should work.